# Install .cer certification file on Linux Red Hat 7.9

Tags: linux, rhel, certificates

I got a `.cer` public key file,say `noob.cer`, that I must install or import to a Linux Red Hat server through command line in order to connect to a domain.

I have searched and I only found info on how to do it with `crt` or `cert`.

I'm a total beginner in this kind of procedure.

How can I do this task?.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you, the idea is to install or import the .cer file on the OS in order to connect to a domain through port 443, but I don't know how to do it...

Comment: You say "key", but it sounds more like you are maybe describing something like a root certificate/issuer that you want your machine to trust as a certificate authority (which would make some tools, like curl and wget trust certs issued by this authority)

Comment: Files with the extension `.cer` are typically binary encoded SSL certificates. Most web servers, such as Apache require `.pem` (base64) encoded SSL certificates. You will also need the matching private key. Therefore, it is very important that you clearly describe what you are trying to do, the server software, who issued the certificate, etc. You mention Red Hat, but that is not important. It is the web server software (Apache, Nginx, etc) that is relevant. There are numerous guides on the Internet on how to setup a web server with SSL.

Comment: To know for certain what you have, run this command `openssl x509 -noout -text -in noob.cer`.